# Truth sets and set diagrams

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

I am confused on how to produce truth sets from propositional logic statements
For example:

$(p \land q) \implies \lnot r$

How would I turn this into a truth set, which could then be used to create a venn diagram.

I have produced a truth table which produced the result FTTTTTTT

Really unsure on how to approach this.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to compute a truth set for a propositional logic statement? That doesn't seem to make much sense to me - what would the members of the truth sets be, if not individuals from some domain which are being predicated over by the formula, as in predicate logic?

Comment: P, Q and R are truth sets of p, q and r.

Comment: Then the phrasing "how to produce truth sets from propositional logic statements " was rather confusing and it's unclear to me what you want to know. If you already have your truth sets, then what else do you want to produce before being able to arrange those sets in a Venn diagram?

Comment: Question in full I am asking is: Assuming that P, Q and R are truth sets of p, q and r respectively. State the truth
set of (p ∧ q) → ¬r and draw a Venn diagram that represents this truth set.

Comment: P∩Q - notation like this for example

Comment: Define truth set.

Answer (score 1):

Any triple $P, Q, R$ satisfying $P\cap Q \subset R^c$ should work. Take for instance $P=\mathbb{N}$ the natural numbers, $Q=\{2n| n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ the set of all even numbers and $R$ the set of all irrational numbers (like $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$). Then $P \cap Q$ is the set of all even numbers greater or equal than zero, and $R^c$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ the set of all rational numbers (assuming your universe is $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 0):

On truth sets for formulas of propositional logic, see :

Lipschutz, Schaum''s Outline Of Discrete Mathematics ( look for " truth set" in the index).

and

Rudolf Carnap , Introduction To Symbolic Logic And Its Applications ( where logical implication is explicitly defined via the set-theoretic notion of inclusion).

Notation: Let's denote by S(X) the truth set of the formula X. ( Here, X can be an atomic proposition as well as a compound sentence)

Definitions:

(1) the truth set of a formula  is the set of all cases ( all n-tuples corresponding to a row of the truth table)  in which the formula is true.

(2) a formula is valid ( is a tautology) if and only if it's truth set is equal to the universal set

(3)  a formula X logically implies a formula Y ( or, if you prefer, Y is a logical consequence of X) if and only if  S(X) is a SUBSET of S(Y).

Here you have 3 atomic propositions, so the universe ( universal set) has 8 elements ( that are ordered sets of 3 truth values).

Let's say ( as a convention) that P is the first sentence, that Q is is the second and that R is the third.

Then here , the universal set is the set that has as elements the following 3-tuples ( and you will recognize here the 8 rows of your truth-table) 
(T,T,T)
(T,T,F)
(T,F,T)
(T,F,F)
(F,T,T)
(F,T,F)
(F,F,T)
(F,F,F)

Now, take each element ( each 3-tuple) of the universal set such that your formula is true in the case corresponding to the 3-tuple, and put all these 3-tuples together in a new set. This new set is the " truth set" of your formula.

Now if you want to use a Venn diagram to prove that your formula is not a tautology ( that is, is not valid)  you have two options:

(1) look at the truth set of your formula and decide whether it's truth set is identical to the universal set; if there is at least one 3-tuple that does not belong to the truth set of your formula, then it is not a tautology;

(2) "create" a set S(P&Q) ( the truth set of the formula P&Q ), create also a set S(~R)  and show that S(P&Q)  it is NOT  a subset of S(~R) .In other words, show using a diagram, that there is at least one 3-tuple that does belong to S(P&Q) but does not belong to S(~R)

Notice: S(P&Q) will be, however, a subset of your universe, and will have some 3-tuples from U as elements, namely the 3-tuples (TTT) and (TTF). The reason why it is not a subset of the truth set of (~R) is that (TTT) belongs to S(P&Q) but not to S(~R)

Comment: Can one motivate the (-1) please. I gave references, not " light" ones. Lipschutz is a great math teacher and Carnap one of the greatest logicians in the 20th century.  True I did not give the answer to the exercice, since precisely it is an exercise. But I have indicated the method to arrive easily at the correct answer. At least I  tried to.